# disable scrolling when trigger owl carousel on mobile device

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I noticed when using Owl Carousel 2, while slide the item in mobile viewing, the browser also can be move up and down. Try to disabling the scroll function when trigger the Owl Carousel 2 prev and next function in mobile but it still doesn't work.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:5,
    nav:true,
    items:2,
});
// $('.owl-carousel').bind("mousewheel", function() {return false;});
$('.owl-carousel').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.stopPropagation(); alert('allow scroll');});
```

Appreciated the answer from expert out here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I made this work with the help of [OwlCarousel2 events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/events.html).

There are 2 events we can use together for this purpose:

1. `drag.owl.carousel` fires when user start to drag
2. `dragged.owl.carousel` fires when dragging finished

And this make it work like how we want it:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    //  your options
});

owl.on('drag.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

owl.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

So; it use css overflow to disable scrolling when dragging started and enables it back when it finished.

Answer (score 1):

This works on iOS & VueJS.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
    //  your options
})

// disable scroll
owl.on('drag.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})

// enable scroll
owl.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
        return true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

look for the below piece of code in `custom.js` file of your project

```
Owl.Defaults = {
        items: 3,
        loop: false,
        center: false,
        rewind: false,

        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: true,}
```

change the things to below:-

```
touchDrag:false,
```

and owl-carousel will simply stop scrolling horizontally both on mobile and desktop drag!

Answer (score 1):

For `owlcarousel2`, you can use `mouseDrag` option.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    mouseDrag:false
});
```

Reference https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Answer (score 0):

in owl.js

mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false,
pullDrag: false,
freeDrag: false,